# JSLink Was Rendering Then Stopped

Tags: 2013, jslink, client-side-rendering

I have two JSLinks on Custom List Webparts on my page -- one for a bootstrap slider, which is working fine continuously, and one for an announcements webpart.  The announcements webpart was working fine, until I changed the variable for date from the Created field to a custom calculated field called Date to render the date in a particular format.  After that change, the JSLink never rendered anymore even when I reverted back to the previous version.  Any thoughts?  MDS is not activated. Here is the original code:

```
    (function () {
    var itemCtx = {};
    itemCtx.Templates = {};
        itemCtx.Templates.Header = "<div class='announcements-wrapper'><ul class='announcements-headings'>"
        itemCtx.Templates.Item = announcements;
        itemCtx.Templates.Footer = "</ul></div>";
    itemCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
    itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 99;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);
    })();

    function announcements(ctx){
        var headliner = ctx.CurrentItesm.Title;
        var body = ctx.CurrentItem.Body;

        var msg = body.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
        var author = ctx.CurrentItem.Author[0].title;
        var date = ctx.CurrentItem.Created;
        var msgLimit = 355;
        var html = "<li><div class='announcements-item'><div class='announcements-date'>" + date + "</div><h2 class='announcements-title'>" + headliner + "</h2> <p>" + msg + "</p><br/>Read More </div></li>";


if (msg.length > msgLimit){
 msg = msg.substring(0,msgLimit);
}
        return html
}
```

Using SP2013 OnPrem.  Also checked that the url was correct and I am using ~site/../..javascript.js in the Misc input box.  Note, that I can see that the JS is loading as in Dev Tools, I can see it as a source.  I'm really baffled considering it was fine earlier.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo here `var headliner = ctx.CurrentItesm.Title;` that probably breaks your whole function.

Should be:

`var headliner = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;`

Comment: Thank you for the catch!  Unfortunately, that still didn't do anything :\.  I've found that typically if it is actually loading, there'd be an Uncaught TypeError & the webpart is blank for coding problems.  But for some reason, it just loads the list as normal so to me it doesn't seem like it is loading at all.  I tested by using the same BaseID as my slider, & only the slider showcased a TypeError until I changed the BaseID again.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error.  Entered wrong number for the ListTemplateType. Announcements TypeID is 104.  This resolved the issue.